# How to iterate the different user ids given under @Before, for same test case under @After?

Tags: java, excel, junit4

I want to iterate the different user ids given under @Before, for same test case under @After.
i.e. I need to login using userid and perform the testcase and then again login using different userid which is provided in excel sheet and again perform the same test case.
Am using for each loop. but after performing testClientName() once, again it only goes to before().

Can any one help me please?

```
@Before
public void before() throws Exception{
    driver.get("https://url.aspx");
    for (String userID : ReadExcel.getUserIds(file)) {

    login1.checkCheckBox();
    login1.loginWithCredentials(userID, "1234", "password");
    }
}

@Test
public void testClientName(){
    if(options.isOptionsEnabled()){
        classicApp.selectClassicAppVersion();
        List<String> classicAppList = classicApp.getAppClientName();
        System.out.println(classicAppList);
    }
    else if(classicApp.hasClassicClientName()){
        List<String> classicAppList = classicApp.getAppClientName();
        System.out.println(classicAppList); 
    }
    else if(betaApp.hasBetaClientName()){
        List<String> betaAppList = betaApp.getBetaClientName();
        System.out.println(betaAppList);
        }
    else{
        System.out.println("Failed login");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests). Move the code that reads the logins from the excel sheet into a method and annotate it with `@Parameters` and you can move the login code into the test itself.